# Subgroup Proof Verification: Show that H is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that H is a subgroup of G when:

G = $\left \langle C(\mathbb{R}), + \right \rangle, H =\left \{ {f\in C(\mathbb{R}): \int_{0}^{1}}f(x)dx=0\right \}$

where C = continuous.

In order to prove subgroups, I know you must first prove the operation and then the inverse's existence. 
For the operation I have:

Let $f, g \in\ H$. Then, $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=0$ and $\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx=0$.

Thus, f + g = $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx + g(x)dx =0. $ Therefore, f+g $\in\ H$.

I'm more unsure of the inverse, as I don't know if I've chosen the correct one. However, I have:

Let $f\in\ H$. Then, $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=0$. As a result,$ -f = \int_{0}^{1} -f(x)dx=-0 = 0$.  Thus, $-f\in\ H $.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean that.

Comment: You can't write $f + g = \int_0^1 (f(x) + g(x)) \, dx$. You don't use $=$ that way. Also, write $\int_0^1 (f(x) + g(x)) \, dx$, not $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx + g(x) \, dx$. Except for these problems with notation, your argument is correct. You also want to check that the zero function belongs to $H$, as Pyrazolam says in a comment below.

Comment: You must also show that $H$ is nonempty as this is a necessary condition of the Subgroup Test. We know that $z(x) = 0 \in H$ because $\int_0^1z(x)\,dx = 0$. This shows that $H \neq \varnothing$

Comment: It's correct. More simply, you can say $H$ is a subgroup because it is the kernel of the group homomorphism $f\mapsto \int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx$ from $G$ to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I'll add a nonempty argument and fix notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $H$ is a subgroup,  it is enough show $0\in H$ and $f-g\in H$ for all $f,g\in H$.

Cleary, $0\in H$. MOreover $f-g\in H$ iff $\int_0^1f(x)-g(x)dx=0$ iff $\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx$. The last is true cause $f,g\in H$.